# How to include curl header or library in C compiler(mingw)(on WINDOWS)?

Tags: c, windows, compilation, mingw, libcurl

I want to include `curl.h` to use the functions included there for my C program and I downloaded them. By them I mean to say `.h`,`.c`,`.a` files i.e. a whole library(curl library). Following is the location to `curl.h`:

```
C:\CURL\include\curl
```

Following is the location to `libcurl.a` :

```
C:\CURL\lib
```

The problem is that I am not able to compile the program correctly as I am thrown error each time.

I tried including path where `curl/curl.h` resides:

```
gcc -IC:/CURL/include test.c -o run -lcurl
```

Error I get:

```
C:/Program Files (x86)/Embarcadero/Dev-Cpp/TDM-GCC-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lcurl

collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Thinking opps, I should have given the path to `libcurl.a`, I tried including path where `curl/curl.h` resides and path where `libcurl.a` resides(i don't know if it is corrent to use `-I` twice):

gcc -IC:/CURL/include -IC:/CURL/lib -lcurl test.c -o run

I was still wrong and Error I get:

```
C:/Program Files (x86)/Embarcadero/Dev-Cpp/TDM-GCC-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lcurl

collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I also tried replacing `-lcurl` with `-llibcurl`,`-llibcurl.a`,`curl.a` while keeping other syntax unchanged for the sake of satisfaction or something like touch and go of if this could be right or that could be right way.

Had I ever entered correct syntax for compiling?

Where am I mistaken in compilation? Please help me in this. Suggest the correct and best way to compile and if possible with **`makefile`**.

Comment: `-L` is for libraries, `-I` is for header files.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: @273K, actually I am not getting any `undefined reference` error. I don't know but I guess I am not being able to link library, As I mentioned earlier in the question can you please help me with correct syntax and possibly a `makefile` maybe at bare level.

Comment: @273K, Thanks for your `-L` option. I tried `gcc -IC:/CURL/include -LC:/CURL/lib -lcurl test.c -o run` and it generated error:`skipping incompatible C:/CURL/lib/libcurl.a when searching for -lcurl`

Comment: Try to download the compatible libcurl.

Comment: I downloaded and now the same command is generating `undefined reference` to certain functions.

Answer (score 0):

> gcc -IC:/CURL/include test.c -o run -lcurl

If you want to add the path directory to the `curl.h`, use `-I` option, but if you want to also link your program, and do it with `-lcurl`, then you need also to add the path to the library binaries with `-Lc:/CURL/lib` option.

```
gcc -IC:/CURL/include test.c -o run -LC:/CURL/lib -lcurl
```

This will, probably, work as expected.

Comment: The problem was solved anyway thanks for your effort. Please do check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74833527/how-do-i-include-a-needed-c-library-using-gcc-in-visual-studio-code-on-windows?noredirect=1#comment132079616_74833527) and help on that too.