# How do I include a needed C library using GCC in Visual Studio Code on Windows?

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio-code, gcc

I am trying to compile a simple code in C with reference to [this](https://www.linuxfordevices.com/tutorials/linux/fetching-web-pages-using-libcurl) example. This is the code which uses curl library in C.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>

int main(void) {
     system("cls");
     CURL* curl = curl_easy_init();

     if (!curl) {
          fprintf(stderr, "[-] Failed Initializing Curl\n");
          exit(-1);
     }

     CURLcode res;
     curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.google.com");
     res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

     if (res != CURLE_OK) {
          fprintf(stderr, "[-] Could Not Fetch Webpage\n[+] Error : %s\n", curl_easy_strerror(res));
          exit(-2);
     }

     curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
     return 0;
}
```

Using the following command to compile this code to produce `run.exe`:

> gcc curl1.c -o run.exe -IC:/CURL/include -LC:/CURL/lib -l curl

And if I run the `run.exe` as such:

> ./run

According to the above mentioned link the output must be fetched webpage of `https://www.google.com` but it does nothing, absolutely nothing. Not a single line of webpage, not a single line of error.

What exactly is the problem? I am not able to figure out. The `problems` section in vs code is saying:

```
#include errors detected. Please update your includePath. IntelliSense features for this translation unit (C:\Users\CPN\Desktop\LIBRARIES\libcurl\curl1.c) will be provided by the Tag Parser.
cannot open source file "curl/curl.h"
```

I can not recognize what the problem it is talking while it lets to compile and run the program without giving any errors. How do I resolve this? Is there some extra setting that I have to set in Vs Code for this? If yes then please tell me how to do this.

Comment: How do you know it didn't fetch the page? You didn't tell it to write a file.

Comment: Is there a curl.h file on your computer?

Comment: @stark, I don't know exactly as I am just beginning to learn curl library.

Comment: @stark, yes I do have at `C:/CURL/include/curl`. Can you please tell what exactly is showing in Vs code problem as `include error detected....`(which I already mentioned in the question)

Comment: VSCode is just an editor. You have to provide it with a compiler toolchain just like how you would provide a compiler toolchain with any other editor. It does not come with native built in ways to include certain files/folder. You have to do it via a makefile. Perhaps you are confusing VSCode with Visual Studio IDE?

Comment: @stark, I did not tell it to write a file but as the tutorial suggest(link I posted in initial part of question) and other tutorials at youtube show it directly in terminal.As I already told I am just trying to learn so I can not understand what things are going on.

Comment: C:/CURL is not the typical place for a compiler to find a header file. You need to tell the compiler to look there or to install the header in a place that it will look.

Comment: @Tryer, yeah hence I am asking so in my question where the other changes I should make. I am I have mentioned required path to header `curl.h` and library `libcurl.a` in `gcc` command(you can check in post). It compiles with no error but vs code is showing problems. I could even run `run.exe` but is does nothing.

Comment: @stark, yeah as i mentioned earlier i may have been in confusion so i am asking what changes should i make and how? Can you tell me how to make things work and how to tell my compiler to do so.

Comment: What is the location of `curl/curl.h`, **relative to** `stdio.h` and `stdlib.h`? Try to place your cURL library (curl directory and all of its contents) in the same directory where your `stdio.h` and `stdlib.h` are located.

Comment: @FiddlingAway, should I place `curl.h` (`C:/CURL/include`) only or `libcurl.a` too?

Comment: @अनुपम Here's what I did. I placed my `run.c` file on my Desktop (no special reason, just so it would be easily accessible) - `C:\Users\Admin\Desktop`. The curl directory was also placed on my Desktop, so it would be on the same level as the `run.c`. The location of `curl.h` within the curl directory is `curl\include\curl\curl.h`. Then, in the `run.c` file, I changed this => `#include <curl/curl.h>` to this => `#include "curl/include/curl/curl.h"`. Try to change way you `include` `curl.h` inside your C file, and see if it will compile.

Comment: @stark, the program, as shown writes the downloaded page to `stdout`, as if you were executing the `curl` program.  Don't confound people more than they are.

Comment: @अनुपम, did you get any warning/error when you run the `gcc` command, as you show above?

Comment: @LuisColorado, he is just doing the same thing in the same way(making fun as if it is different), I guess. Keeping `.c` file in that directory he suggest won't do anything.

Comment: @LuisColorado, I did not give any error message. It compiles successfully and if I try to run the `.exe`, it does nothing and not even writes any single character in `stdout`, programming in Windows machine.

Comment: try a hello world program `int main() { printf("Hello, world\n"); }` to see what happens.  You need to `#include <stdio.h>` first, but nothing more.

Answer (score 0):

The program you post runs complete, from beginning to end.  Next is the output from it, running on an Ubuntu desktop computer (I have deleted the `system("cls");` call, as it is windows specific, and I don't have proper substitute in Ubuntu):

```
$ run
<!doctype html><html itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage" lang="fi"><head><meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type"><meta content="/logos/doodles/2022/seasonal-holidays-2022-6753651837109831.4-law.gif" itemprop="image"><meta content="Vuoden 2022 juhlapyh�t" property="twitter:title"><meta content=" " 

... <a lot of hidden output, several pages long> ... 

        </body></html>$ _    <<--- this is where shell prompt and cursor ends, as no final newline is included in the body of the HTML output.
```

I recommend you to redirect program output to a file, as shown next, to save the normal program output into a file you can inspect.  I don't know the reason you cannot get any output, but, at least in Linux, it runs as you told.

```
$ run >file.out
$ ls -l file.out
-rw-rw-r-- 1 lcu lcu 49962 Dec 19 14:55 file.out
$ _
```

I recommend also to erase the `system()` call at the beginning, so it doesn't interfere in the program output (it shouldn't, as it is executed before the whole stuff, but try it, and see what happens)

Comment: So, I guess it depends on OS. I am running it on my windows machine.

Comment: I know you are running on a windows machine.  I'd try to take off the `system("cls");` call (which is not standard) and run it redirecting the output to a file, as explained in the answer.  There should be no problem also in Windows, but I'm not able to test it on a windows system.  Don't guess so quickly, probably is something related on how windows displays the output, and not that no output is actually shown.

Comment: I guess I have to make the code write in `stdout` in the Windows system but as a beginner I got no idea to do so.

Comment: nope... the code actually writes to `stdout` directly from curl library.  You should do nothing to get it working (as I did) but if you are running it on the Windows console or from an IDE, it's probable that you don't see the output because the standard output in Windows is simulated somehow (it is done so because the input/output redirection is not a native feature of windows)

Comment: This is the reason for me to ask you to eliminate superfluous calls (like the `system("cls");` call you do at the beginning) from your code and run it.  Also, you can try running your program from a `cmd.exe` window in your computer.